# Having returned to the UK from Italy I use the remainder of my C type multi entry Stati Schengen to visit Greece

Tags: schengen

As the title states can I use my remaining visa now to travel elsewhere within the Schengen zone after recently returning from my original holiday in Italy.

I'm an Indian national with ILR in the UK married to a British national. Previously travelled to Italy without any visa (on the assumption that as accompanied by my spouse, a visa wouldn't be necessary - however decided not to risk it this time as was frowned upon by German airline.)